# How to reboot centos in docker?

Tags: docker, centos7

How to reboot centos in docker ?

I had pulled centos 7 from docker

use the 'shutdown -r now'

The console said 'Failed to talk to init daemon.'

I also used  'reboot -f' , and get the 
'Rebooting.
Failed to reboot: Operation not permitted' for rsp

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to restart container?

if it is necessary you can use
`docker exec -it <container name> reboot`
or you can stop container and start it again 
`docker stop -f <container name>`
then
`docker start <container name>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are logged in to your container and trying to "reboot" the container:

e.g. `docker run -i -t centos /bin/bash`
and then `reboot`

You shouldn't do is.

Please use `docker run/start/stop...`.